# Symofny 5 ParamConverter broken after update

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

The last composer update completely broken my project based on Symfony5:

`php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Error: Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry or null, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given`

I've already updated all the references of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry  to Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry a long time ago, according to the Symfony documentation

Any help would be appreciated

**List of installed packages:**

```
beberlei/doctrineextensions          v1.2.6   
cmen/google-charts-bundle            3.2.1    
craue/formflow-bundle                3.3.2    
doctrine/annotations                 1.10.3   
doctrine/cache                       1.10.1   
doctrine/collections                 1.6.5    
doctrine/common                      2.13.3   
doctrine/data-fixtures               1.4.3    
doctrine/dbal                        2.10.2   
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             2.1.0    
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle    3.3.1    
doctrine/event-manager               1.1.0    
doctrine/inflector                   1.4.3    
doctrine/instantiator                1.3.1    
doctrine/lexer                       1.2.1    
doctrine/orm                         v2.7.3   
doctrine/persistence                 1.3.7    
doctrine/reflection                  1.2.1    
doctrine/sql-formatter               1.1.0    
easycorp/easyadmin-bundle            v2.3.9   
egulias/email-validator              2.1.18   
friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle     2.2.0    
friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle    2.6.0    
guzzlehttp/guzzle                    6.5.5    
guzzlehttp/promises                  v1.3.1   
guzzlehttp/psr7                      1.6.1    
helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle         10.0.4   
incenteev/composer-parameter-handler v2.1.4   
jms/metadata                         2.3.0    
jumbojett/openid-connect-php         v0.8.0   
knplabs/knp-components               v2.3.6   
knplabs/knp-menu                     v3.1.1   
knplabs/knp-menu-bundle              v3.0.0   
knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle         v5.2.0   
knplabs/knp-snappy                   v1.2.1   
knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle            v1.7.0   
knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle   v1.34.0  
league/oauth2-client                 2.4.1    
maennchen/zipstream-php              2.1.0    
markbaker/complex                    1.4.8    
markbaker/matrix                     1.2.0    
mashape/unirest-php                  v3.0.4   
monolog/monolog                      1.25.4   
myclabs/php-enum                     1.7.6    
nikic/php-parser                     v4.5.0   
ninsuo/symfony-collection            2.1.33   
ocramius/package-versions            1.4.2    
pagerfanta/pagerfanta                v2.3.0   
paragonie/random_compat              v9.99.99 
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet             1.13.0   
phpseclib/phpseclib                  2.0.27   
psr/cache                            1.0.1    
psr/container                        1.0.0    
psr/event-dispatcher                 1.0.0    
psr/http-message                     1.0.1    
psr/link                             1.0.0    
psr/log                              1.1.3    
psr/simple-cache                     1.0.1    
pugx/autocompleter-bundle            v1.5.0   
ralouphie/getallheaders              3.0.3    
royopa/fpdf-symfony2                 3.0      
sensio/framework-extra-bundle        v5.5.6   
sensiolabs/ansi-to-html              v1.2.0   
setasign/fpdf                        1.8.1    
setasign/fpdi                        1.6.2    
setasign/fpdi-fpdf                   1.6.2    
sg/datatablesbundle                  v1.2.1   
studio-42/elfinder                   2.1.57   
swiftmailer/swiftmailer              v6.2.3   
symfony/contracts                    v2.1.2   
symfony/debug                        v4.4.10  
symfony/maker-bundle                 v1.19.0  
symfony/monolog-bundle               v3.5.0   
symfony/phpunit-bridge               v5.1.2   
symfony/polyfill-apcu                v1.17.1  
symfony/polyfill-ctype               v1.17.1  
symfony/polyfill-iconv               v1.17.1  
symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme       v1.17.1  
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu            v1.17.1  
symfony/polyfill-intl-idn            v1.17.1  
symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer     v1.17.1  
symfony/polyfill-mbstring            v1.17.1  
symfony/polyfill-php72               v1.17.0  
symfony/polyfill-php73               v1.17.1  
symfony/polyfill-php80               v1.17.1  
symfony/polyfill-uuid                v1.17.1  
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle           v3.4.0   
symfony/symfony                      v5.1.2   
tetranz/select2entity-bundle         v2.10.1  
twig/twig                            v3.0.3   
vich/uploader-bundle                 1.14.0   
willdurand/jsonp-callback-validator  v1.1.0   
yectep/phpspreadsheet-bundle         v0.1.1
```

Comment: Any update on this task?

Comment: Look like updating/upgrading did the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update Php Version on your system to 7.4
2. Run composer upgrade

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happend to me. Just run the command `composer update`