# Issues Symfony 5 object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I tried to make a function that edit/delete an entity object but I have this issue

> App\Entity\Courts object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.

***{slug}*** : get the type of 'categories'

***{action}*** : get the action (delete or edit) - Delete works

***{id}*** : get the id of the object

Here the part that creates the problem :

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/{slug}/{action}/{id}", name="{slug}_{action}")
 */
public function delete(Courts $courts, Domains $domains, Request $request, $slug, $action, $id)
{
    switch ($slug) {
        case 'courts':
            $repos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Courts::class);
            $form = $this->createForm(ECategoriesFormType::class, $courts);
            break;
        case 'domains':
            $repos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Domains::class);
            $form = $this->createForm(ECategoriesFormType::class, $domains);
            break;
        default:
            // will redirect to admin page if user try to bypass by url with bad slug
            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: there seems to be similar issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62576843/symofny-5-paramconverter-broken-after-update

Comment: use @ParamConverter annotation to clear up for symfony how to get a Courts object (and the others). see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Comment: Your {action} is not going to work as expected.  It will match against either delete or edit and will always end up calling whichever method you have defined first.  As a minimum, change your url to /admin/{slug}/delete/{id} and add a second url for your edit method /admin/{slug}/edit/{id}.  Your route name needs to be adjusted as well.  Names will not be created dynamically so you need something like 'admin_slug_delete' and 'admin_slug_edit'.  Become familiar with 'bin/console debug:router; and follow the examples in the docs.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Which of these lines triggers that problem?

Comment: Problem was that  the "Domains $domain and Courts $courts" trigger the error but my problem is solved with the solutions I proposed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved, here is my solution :

It dynamically generates an url like `admin/courts/add/edit/2` or `admin/domains/delete/3`

```
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/{slug}/{action}/{id}", name="{slug}_{action}")
     */
  public function delete(CourtsRepository $courtsRepository,
                           DomainsRepository $domainsRepository,
                           Request $request, $slug, $action, $id)
    {
        /*
         *  Get the repos for edit or delete update
         *  Check if the action is edit to get the execute query
         */
        switch ($slug) {
            case 'courts':
                $repos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Courts::class);
                $form = ($action == "edit") ? $this->createForm(ACategoriesFormType::class, $courtsRepository->find($id)) : false;
                break;
            case 'domains':
                $repos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Domains::class);
                $form = ($action == "edit") ? $this->createForm(ACategoriesFormType::class, $domainsRepository->find($id)): false;
                break;
            default:
                // will redirect to admin page if user try to bypass by url with bad slug
                return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');
                break;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Glad you got something working but you are trying to do too much in one method. Maybe you have a reason but you really should consider having a CourtController and a DomainController each having individual  delete/edit methods.

Comment: @Cerad Yes, I thought about it but we have a lot of entities and don't want to have one controller for each of them that does exactly the same thing.